# Call PHP function on button click

Tags: php, html, function, onsubmit

This is the PHP function, it is messy right now (redundant lines) that I will clean up after.
I am stuck right now, really trying to keep the whole process to one page:

```
<?php function signpetitiion() {
$API_KEY = 'MYAPIKEY';
$REQUEST_URL = 'https://api.change.org/v1/petitions/get_id';
$PETITION_URL = 'https://www.change.org/p/URLTOMYPETITION';
$parameters = array(
  'api_key' => $API_KEY,
  'petition_url' => $PETITION_URL

}


?>
```

So this doesn't work because it is browser side:

```
<form onsubmit="sign_petitiion()">
```

How do I get this function to run with a button click?
Should I convert to a JS script? if so how?

Or call with AJAX? if so how?

```
if(isset($_POST['go'])){

    <input type="submit" name="go" method="post">
```

Question closed as I was typing my answer

I know this question (in different ways) has been asked before,
I had read through them but the answers were either too complicated for me (NEWB) or just a comment saying you can't.

Any ways I have found my answer,

I had to change these 2 lines

```
function sign_petitiion() {
```

to

```
     if(isset($_POST['go'])){
```

and then

```
<form onsubmit="sign_petitiion()">
```

to

```
    <form method="Post" class="sign" action="mypage.php">
```

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You can't call a PHP function from Javascript directly. You can either submit to a particular PHP page and refresh the page, or do an Ajax call to a PHP page. But you can't call a PHP function. You'd have to give your submit or Ajax call a parameter to tell what function you want the PHP page to run.

Comment: So I have been doing a lot of reading and it seems I should use Ajx?
I am just a newb working on a personal webpage so its a bit over my head but Ill keep at it.

Or, would it be better to convert this php function to a js script?
and if so, how would I go about that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- HTML-->
<a href='index.php?run=true'>Execute it </a>

//*.php
if($_Get['true']){
    signpetitiion();
}
```

Comment: Some questions sound like: I want to drive fast around that and than up to full speed and again right and fullspeed again, but, i dont where to put the keys in.  Can you help me making that key? :)

Comment: Thanx for quick reply,
I have tried for 2 days now, but just can't get the function to run
I have tried several ways (changed to post as the page is posting)
Just no luck, but I will keep trying.

eg
!code~
        <form method="Post" class="sign" action="pet3.php?run=true">
<a href='pet3.php?run=true'>Execute it </a>

          <?php
//  if($_get['true'])
  //  sign_petitiion();
  
  if($_Post['true']){
    sign_petitiion();
}
  
?>

Comment: original question edited'
Thank you @Kisaragi for pointing me in right direction